# Are public fields ever OK?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization, field

Before you react from the gut, as I did initially, read the whole question please.  I know they make you feel dirty, I know we've all been burned before and I know it's not "good style" but, are public fields ever ok?

I'm working on a fairly large scale engineering application that creates and works with an in memory model of a structure (anything from high rise building to bridge to shed, doesn't matter).  There is a TON of geometric analysis and calculation involved in this project.  To support this, the model is composed of many tiny immutable read-only structs to represent things like points, line segments, etc.  Some of the values of these structs (like the coordinates of the points) are accessed tens or hundreds of millions of times during a typical program execution.  Because of the complexity of the models and the volume of calculation, performance is absolutely critical.

I feel that we're doing everything we can to optimize our algorithms, performance test to determine bottle necks, use the right data structures, etc. etc.  I don't think this is a case of premature optimization.  Performance tests **show order of magnitude** (at least) performance boosts when accessing fields directly rather than through a property on the object.  Given this information, and the fact that we can also expose the same information as properties to support data binding and other situations... is this OK?  *Remember, read only fields on immutable structs.*  Can anyone think of a reason I'm going to regret this?

Here's a sample test app:

---

```
struct Point {
    public Point(double x, double y, double z) {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
        _z = z;
    }

    public readonly double _x;
    public readonly double _y;
    public readonly double _z;

    public double X { get { return _x; } }
    public double Y { get { return _y; } }
    public double Z { get { return _z; } }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        const int loopCount = 10000000;

        var point = new Point(12.0, 123.5, 0.123);

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        double x, y, z;
        double calculatedValue;
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
            x = point._x;
            y = point._y;
            z = point._z;
            calculatedValue = point._x * point._y / point._z;
        }
        sw.Stop();
        double fieldTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("Direct field access: " + fieldTime);

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
            x = point.X;
            y = point.Y;
            z = point.Z;
            calculatedValue = point.X * point.Y / point.Z;
        }
        sw.Stop();
        double propertyTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("Property access: " + propertyTime);

        double totalDiff = propertyTime - fieldTime;
        Console.WriteLine("Total difference: " + totalDiff);
        double averageDiff = totalDiff / loopCount;
        Console.WriteLine("Average difference: " + averageDiff);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

---

**result:**
Direct field access: 3262
Property access: 24248
Total difference: 20986
Average difference: 0.00020986

---

It's *only* 21 seconds, but why not?

Comment: I can't see the harm in this case.

Comment: Are the performance tests done on a release build?

Comment: Yeah- putting it in release mode changes the stats a LOT.

Comment: Release build results:  
Direct field access: 112  
Property access: 499  
Total difference: 387  
Average difference: 3.87E-05  


Excellent point, big difference (although still more performant with fields)

Comment: If you didn't compile as Release rerun your tests.  the JITer will try inline Properties and for as simple as these are the optimizer may make them work the same.

Comment: Try a release build and running directly from an exe instead of through the debugger.  See my answer.

Comment: In a non trivial program though, where these points are created based on user entered data and passed around to a lot of components as well as being created and destroyed frequently, would the optimization be the same?  I'll have to performance test with the real app to see.

Comment: @MKing- this is also interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646779/does-c-inline-properties

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379041/what-is-the-best-practice-for-using-public-fields)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are public fields faster than properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632831/why-are-public-fields-faster-than-properties)

Comment: Answering the title solely: Unity3D, for example, requires them if you're going to use their automatic tweaking GUIs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your test isn't really being fair to the property-based versions.  The JIT is smart enough to inline simple properties so that they have a runtime performance equivalent to that of direct field access, but it doesn't seem smart enough (today) to detect when the properties access constant values.

In your example, the entire loop body of the field access version is optimized away, becoming just:

```
for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
00000025  xor         eax,eax 
00000027  inc         eax  
00000028  cmp         eax,989680h 
0000002d  jl          00000027 
}
```

whereas the second version, is actually performing the floating point division on each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
00000094  xor         eax,eax 
00000096  fld         dword ptr ds:[01300210h] 
0000009c  fdiv        qword ptr ds:[01300218h] 
000000a2  fstp        st(0) 
000000a4  inc         eax  
000000a5  cmp         eax,989680h 
000000aa  jl          00000096 
}
```

Making just two small changes to your application to make it more realistic makes the two operations practically identical in performance.

First, randomize the input values so that they aren't constants and the JIT isn't smart enough to remove the division entirely.

Change from:

```
Point point = new Point(12.0, 123.5, 0.123);
```

to:

```
Random r = new Random();
Point point = new Point(r.NextDouble(), r.NextDouble(), r.NextDouble());
```

Secondly, ensure that the results of each loop iteration are used somewhere:

Before each loop, set calculatedValue = 0 so they both start at the same point.  After each loop call Console.WriteLine(calculatedValue.ToString()) to make sure that the result is "used" so the compiler doesn't optimize it away.  Finally, change the body of the loop from "calculatedValue = ..." to "calculatedValue += ..." so that each iteration is used.

On my machine, these changes (with a release build) yield the following results:

```
Direct field access: 133
Property access: 133
Total difference: 0
Average difference: 0
```

Just as we expect, the x86 for each of these modified loops is identical (except for the loop address)

```
000000dd  xor         eax,eax 
000000df  fld         qword ptr [esp+20h] 
000000e3  fmul        qword ptr [esp+28h] 
000000e7  fdiv        qword ptr [esp+30h] 
000000eb  fstp        st(0) 
000000ed  inc         eax  
000000ee  cmp         eax,989680h 
000000f3  jl          000000DF (This loop address is the only difference)
```

Comment: Great answer. I knew the difference shouldn't be that big.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough response!  You're right, and this more closely mimics what would happen in my actual application.

Comment: Just run the optimized release build outside of the debugger (If you start a managed process with a debugger attached, it will change the JIT behavior).  Then, when it is waiting at the Console.ReadLine at the end, attach the VS debugger to the process (Tools->Attach To Process).  Then right-click on a stack frame in the right method in the call stack window and select "Go To Disassembly"

Comment: Awesome answer. This demonstrates a *crucial* factor when measuring performance: ALWAYS MEASURE REAL-WORLD PERFORMANCE. Unless you are an expert on building benchmarks, you WILL write a benchmark that measures some completely meaningless thing, like this one did.

Answer (score 21):

Given that you deal with immutable objects with readonly fields, I would say that you have hit the one case when I don't find public fields to be a dirty habit.

Comment: Agreed, but ideally only when there is a demonstrable performance requirement.

Answer (score 10):

IMO, the "no public fields" rule is one of those rules which are technically correct, but unless you are designing a library intended to be used by the public it is unlikely to cause you any problem if you break it.

Before I get too massively downvoted, I should add that *encapsulation* is a good thing. Given the invariant "the Value property must be null if HasValue is false", this design is flawed:

```
class A {
    public bool HasValue;
    public object Value;
}
```

However, given that invariant, this design is equally flawed:

```
class A {
    public bool HasValue { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

The correct design is

```
class A {
    public bool HasValue { get; private set; }
    public object Value { get; private set; }

    public void SetValue(bool hasValue, object value) {
        if (!hasValue && value != null)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        this.HasValue = hasValue;
        this.Value    = value;
    }
}
```

(and even better would be to provide an initializing constructor and make the class immutable).

Comment: You had me on edge the entire post as to whether to upvote you, but you earned my upvote with the immutability recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

I know you feel kind of dirty doing this, but it isn't uncommon for rules and guidelines to get shot to hell when performance becomes an issue. For example, quite a few high traffic websites using MySQL have data duplication and denormalized tables. Others [go even crazier](http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql).

Moral of the story - it may go against everything you were taught or advised, but the benchmarks don't lie. If it works better, just do it.

Comment: I'd add a caveat: "if it works better, *and* you actually need the better performance".

Comment: @Luke Many people just assume you need the performance.  I'd add one more caveat that you don't need the performance until there's a problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need that extra performance, then it's *probably* the right thing to do. If you don't need the extra performance then it's probably not.

Rico Mariani has a couple of related posts:

- [Ten Questions on Value-Based Programming](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2006/08/31/performance-quiz-11-ten-questions-on-value-based-programming.aspx)
- [Ten Questions on Value-Based Programming : Solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2006/09/07/performance-quiz-11-ten-questions-on-value-based-programming-solution.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, the only time I would consider using public fields is in a very implementation-specific private nested class.

Other times it just feels too "wrong" to do it.

The CLR will take care of performance by optimising out the method/property (in release builds) so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Right: private implementation details. And even there I would only do it if there are pressing performance or time-pressure reasons. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling a release build and running directly from the exe instead of through the debugger.  If the application was run through a debugger then the JIT compiler will not inline the property accessors.  I was not able to replicate your results.  In fact, each test I ran indicated that there was virtually no difference in execution time.

But, like the others I am not completely oppossed to direct field access.  Especially because it is easy to make the field private and add a public property accessor at a later time without needed make any more code modifications to get the application to compile.

**Edit:** Okay, my initial tests used an int data type instead of double.  I see a huge difference when using doubles. With ints the direct vs. property is virtually the same.  With doubles property access is about 7x slower than direct access on my machine.  This is somewhat puzzling to me.

Also, it is important to run the tests outside of the debugger.  Even in release builds the debugger adds overhead which skews the results.

Comment: Great points, here are the results I get now:

Release build (through debugger):  
Direct field access: 112  
Property access: 494  
Total difference: 382  
Average difference: 3.82E-05  

Release build (direct):  
Direct field access: 4  
Property access: 115  
Total difference: 111  
Average difference: 1.11E-05  

Certainly not no difference, but arguably negligible.

Comment: Interesting.  I admit that I crafted my own test and did not test your exact code, but I am surprised that you saw that much difference.  The difference I saw was always less than 1%.  If I get time I will use your exact code.

Comment: Okay I used your exact code and I got some surprising results.  I edited my answer to reflect that.  It seems that doubles return types are not getting inlined?  Strange.

Comment: You can not change a field to a property, recompile and then expect any references to work. Field pointers do not behave the same as property pointers. Try using an external library with a field referenced from a console app. Now alter the field to become a property and only recompile the library, run the app and the reference will fail.

Comment: @Brett, yeah that is because you have technically changed the public interface.  You will also have a problem with ref parameters. Code that uses reflection may fail. Attached attributes may not be allowable on properties. I could go on and on.  But, for the most part the change is pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I disagree with the other answers, or with your conclusion... but I'd like to know where you get the order of magnitude performance difference stat from.  As I understand the C# compiler, any *simple* property (with no additional code other than direct access to the field), should get inlined by the JIT compiler as a direct access anyway.

The advantedge of using properties even in these simple cases (in most situations) was that by writing it as a property you allow for future changes that might modify the property.  (Although in your case there would not be any such changes in future of course)

Comment: The order of magnitude stat comes from testing, see the initial question:  result:
Direct field access: 3262
Property access: 24248

In this case more like 7.4x slower (not 10x) but similar and other tests produce different results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some scenarios where it is OK (from the Framework Design Guidelines book):

> - DO use constant fields for constants
>     that will never change.
> - DO use public
>     static readonly fields for predefined
>     object instances.

And where it is not:

> - DO NOT assign instances of mutable
>     types to readonly fields.

From what you have stated I don't get why your trivial properties don't get inlined by the JIT?

Comment: The last bullet point is pure hogwash.  It is much easier to reason about state which is encapsulated by an immutable reference to a mutable object, than state which is encapsulated by a mutable object to which a mutable reference is held.  In the former scenario, changes to the mutable object will be reflected in the encapsulating object as long as the latter exists.  In the latter situation, the mutable object may become "detached", such that further changes to it will no longer be reflected in the enclosing object.  There are times when mutable references to mutable objects are needed, ...

Comment: ...as with `List<T>` and its backing array, but knowing whether certain objects will be attached throughout their usable lifetimes is often critical information especially in things like parallel programming.

Comment: The example program shown with that guideline would not be made any clearer by removing `readonly` from the array backing field.  To the contrary, suppose that tag were removed, and suppose one didn't have all the code for `BadDesign`, but one did have the part that was shown.  If object `Foo` executes `int[] Arr1 = bad.Data`, and some time later (after various other operations that leave `Arr1` and `bad` referencing the same objects) performs `bad.Data[0]++;`, will the latter operation affect `Arr1[0]`?  Could you tell without a `readonly` declaration on `data`?

Comment: While it is true that the behavior of a `readonly` declaration on an array-type variable may be unintuitive to anyone who doesn't know .net (less so in vb.net than in C#, since it's clearer that the vb.net `ReadOnly` declaration affects the field, rather than the array type), it's no worse than the property declaration in that regard.  The property that returns a reference to an array is hideous, but making it a read-write property would make things even worse, since even someone who understands .net wouldn't know whether code should update the array in place, or should make a new array and...

Comment: ...store a reference to it back in the original object.  I really wish .net had included an immutable-array type in its original design, and included an abstract `ReadableArray` base type from which both mutable and immutable arrays derived.  Indexing arrays is much more efficient than indexing any other type of collection, and CLR-supported immutable arrays could retain that efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your test to use the temp variables you assign rather than directly access the properties in your calculation you will see a large performance improvement:

```
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
        {
            x = point._x;
            y = point._y;
            z = point._z;
            calculatedValue = x * y / z;
        }
        sw.Stop();
        double fieldTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("Direct field access: " + fieldTime);

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
        {
            x = point.X;
            y = point.Y;
            z = point.Z;
            calculatedValue = x * y / z;
        }
        sw.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'll repeat someone else, but here's my point too if it may help.

Teachings are to give you the tools you need to achieve a certain level of ease when encountering such situations.

The Agile Software development methodology says that you have to first deliver the product to your client no matter what your code might look like. Second, you may optimize and make your code "beautiful" or according to the programming states of the art.

Here, either you or your client require performance. Within your project, PERFORMANCE is CRUCIAL, if I understand correctly.

So, I guess you'll agree with me that we don't care about what the code might look like or whether it respects the "art". Do what you have to to make it performant and powerful! Properties allow your code to "format" the data I/O if required. A property has its own memory address, then it looks for its member address when you return the member's value, so you got two searches of address. If performance is such critical, just do it, and make your immutable members public. :-)

This reflects some others point of view too, if I read correctly. :)

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Types which encapsulate functionality should use properties.  Types which only serve to hold data should use public fields, except in the case of immutable classes (where wrapping fields in read-only properties is the only way to reliably protect them against modification).  Exposing members as public fields essentially proclaims "these members may be freely modified at any time without regard for anything else".  If the type in question is a class type, it further proclaims "anyone who exposes a reference to this thing will be allowing the recipient to change these members at any time in any fashion they see fit."  While one shouldn't expose public fields in cases where such a proclamation would be inappropriate, one should expose public fields in cases where such a proclamation would be appropriate and client code could benefit from the assumptions enabled thereby.