# Is this the only way to make inherited objects?

Tags: java, inheritance, this, parent, super

```
public class Animal
{
    public String name;
    public boolean legs;
    public boolean eyes;

    public Animal(String name, boolean legs, boolean eyes)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.legs = legs;
        this.eyes = eyes;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Dog extends Animal
{
    String name;
    boolean legs;
    boolean eyes;
    public boolean vacinated;
    public boolean rabid;
    public Dog(boolean vacinated, boolean rabid, String name, boolean legs, boolean eyes)
    {
        super(name, legs, eyes);
        this.vacinated = vacinated;
        this.rabid = rabid;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Bulldog extends Dog
{
    String name;
    boolean legs;
    boolean eyes;
    public boolean vacinated;
    public boolean rabid;
    public String breedtype;

    public Bulldog(String breedtype, String name, boolean legs, boolean eyes, boolean vacinated, boolean rabid)
    {
        super(vacinated, rabid, name, legs, eyes);
        this.breedtype = breedtype;
    }
}
```

As you can see, if this keeps going on and on, in other words, if I have a really long inheritance line, would I seriously need to list out every single variable over and over again? I just feel like there is a a much more efficient way to do this.

Comment: *would I seriously need to list out every single variable over and over again?* - No. Your variables are public, you can access them from child classes. If you decide to follow the standard and make them private you will still be able to acces them via setters and getters. So, in both cases, no, you don't have to repeat them.

Comment: So i dont need to re-declare them, but i DO need to have them in my constructors as parameter variables?

Comment: No. You currently have multiple `name` variables in the same class. Since member variables aren't polymorphic, this will near-certainly not do what you expect.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, you still need them in constructor. But you can call `super(...)` as you are already doing to avoid re-assigning them.

Comment: You need a tutorial in objects and classes,  not this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes are violated OOP. You should define common properties which could be inherited to child classes by `protected`. It means child classes can access those

Secondly, the common properties should be defined in parent class and dont need to be re-created in child ones.

P/S: updated by BlackFlash comment. I will use private modifier for such common properties. In the scope of this question, child classes don't need to access parent's properties.

Your classes should be changed as follows:

```
public class Animal
{
  private String name;
  private boolean legs;
  private boolean eyes;

  public Animal(String name, boolean legs, boolean eyes)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.legs = legs;
    this.eyes = eyes;
 }
}

public class Dog extends Animal
{
   private boolean vacinated;
   private boolean rabid;
   private Dog(boolean vacinated, boolean rabid, String name, boolean legs, boolean eyes)
    {
      super(name, legs, eyes);
      this.vacinated = vacinated;
      this.rabid = rabid;
  }
}

public class Bulldog extends Dog
{
   private String breedtype;
   public Bulldog(String breedtype, String name, boolean legs, boolean eyes, boolean vacinated, boolean rabid)
   {
    super(vacinated, rabid, name, legs, eyes);
    this.breedtype = breedtype;
  }
}
```

Comment: *You should define common properties which could be inherited to child classes by protected* - Actually, you should make them private and define setters and getters instead.

Comment: @BackSlash: why cannot use `protected` for common properties?

Comment: @htpvl For example, because `protected` variables can be seen by classes inside the same package too. This means that if at some point you need to manipulate those variables or change some behaviour, you'll have to make a breaking change, requiring all the developers who used that variable to update their code. If you make the variable private and write setters/getters, you'll be able to control that variable and make any change to those methods without breaking other code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8353371/1759845

Comment: @BackSlash: thanks for this useful info. Actually I don't know `protected` ones could be accessed in same package. I learnt OOP by C++ and there is no package in that langugae. anw, it is a new learn. tks again.

Comment: @htpvl Check this for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a violation of the whole OOP concept. You can have common variables in the parent class as `protected` variables so that it can be accessed by that class and its children.

Not only variables but also  common methods can be defined and implemented in parent class as protected.

[Read more here](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/inheritance.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler example of one of the problems with what you're doing:

```
class A {
  String a;

  A(String a) { this.a = a; }
}

class B extends A {
  String a;

  A(String a) { super(a); }
}
```

This code will probably give results that you don't expect:

```
B b = new B("hello");
System.out.println(b.a);  // null
```

This may be surprising to you, because it might appear that you initialized `a` in the constructor of `A`, via the `super(a)` call.

But what's more surprising is that if you cast it to `A`, it *doesn't* print `null`:

```
System.out.println(((A) b).a);  // hello
```

which looks odd: it prints something different when you treat it as a different type.

The problem here is that fields are not polymorphic in Java: the `a` in `B` **hides** the `a` in `A`. Both fields are there, but when you refer to `a` on an variable of type `B`, you get a different field to when you refer to `a` on a variable of type `A`.

For this to work "less confusingly", don't repeat the declaration of `a` in `B`:

```
class A {
  String a;

  A(String a) { this.a = a; }
}

class B extends A {
  A(String a) { super(a); }
}
```

Now:

```
B b = new B("hello");
System.out.println(b.a);  // hello
System.out.println(((A) b).a);  // hello
```